# 32 kw generator feeding two panels

Tags: wiring

I am feeding two 200 amp panels with a 32kw generator using an auto transfer switch. To prevent unsafe generator start up can I wire the utility sensing control using power from each panel to the sensing fuses making sure I have correctly phased each terminal?
 The utility is 400 amp single phase 240/120 volt service feeding the auto transfer switch. Transfer switch feeds each 200 amp panel with 3/0. If I feed the transfer switch utility 240 volt sensing circuit from say panel 1 and the panel is shut off it would cause the generator to start. Thus I need both panels to connect to this circuit. – Mike yesterday

Comment: Is one a sub-panel of the other?  Other than that and the service grounding,  do you have any *cross-wiring* of any kind between the two panels, any place they share hots or neutrals, or a hot comes out of one panel while neutral goes back to the other etc.?

Comment: We'll need *way* more details about your setup here...

Comment: The utility is 400 amp single phase 240/120 volt service feeding the auto transfer switch. Transfer switch feeds each 200 amp panel with 3/0. If I feed the transfer switch utility 240 volt sensing circuit from say panel 1 and the panel is shut off it would cause the generator to start. Thus I need both panels to connect to this circuit.

Comment: How many circuits total do the two panels feed, and how many *can* they feed? It seems that using a single 400A panelboard is the simplest way to solve this problem (splitting panelboards *used* to be needed under pre-2008 NEC editions due to the 42 circuit limit, but that limitation is no more, and you can get single panelboards up to 60 or even 84 circuits nowadays)

Comment: Yes ThreePhaseEel this would be the best. However I did not become involved in the project until the panels were installed. I have considered installing a control relay using NO contacts from panel one and NC from panel 2.

Comment: I used an EATON Auto transfer switch with a control circuit board. I used CT's to sense the current on the line side of the transfer switch this controls the generator an prevents it from starting if either switchboard main is turned off but activates the start sequence if loss of power or the transfer main is turned off.